# TypeError: Cannot read property 'adx' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm a newbie in programming so bear with me please. I spent about two days on this and couldn't find solution. My problem is with the following code:

```
const fs = require('fs');  //Grants access to filesystem
const SMA = require('technicalindicators').SMA;
const ADX = require('technicalindicators').ADX;
const pairsArray = ['ETHBTC','BTCUSD'];
const BFXTrade = require('./BfxTrade');

var bfx = new BFXTrade();
var pairs = {};
var openedPositions = 0;
var profit = 0;
var loss = 0;
var a = {};
var adxValue = {};

const maPeriods = 20;
const adxPeriods = 14;
const trendStrength = 10;

function Manager() {
    for(pair of pairsArray) {
        pairs[pair] = {
            ma: new SMA({period : maPeriods, values :[]}),
            maValue:0,
            prevMaValue:0,
            prevClose:0,
            adx: new ADX({period: adxPeriods, close:[], high:[], low:[]}),
            adxValue: {},
            long:false,
            short:false,
            stopLossPrice:0,
            entryAmount:0,
            entryPrice:0
        }
    }
}

/**
    Start Bot
**/
Manager.prototype.runBot = function(){
    var marketData = {};

    for (pair of pairsArray) {
        marketData[pair] = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/datasets/BFX_'+pair+'_5m.json', 'utf8'));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < marketData[pairsArray[0]].length; i++) {
        for (pair in marketData) {
            updateIndicators(pair, marketData[pair][i]);
        }
    }

//  for( pair in marketData){
//      for(candle of marketData[pair]){
//          calculateMA(pair, candle[2])
//      }
//  }
}

function updateIndicators(pair, price){
    pairs[pair]['maValue'] = pairs[pair]['ma'].nextValue(price[2]);
    pairs[pair]['adxValue'] = pairs[pair]['adx'].nextValue({period: adxPeriods, close: price[2], high: price[3], low: price[4]});
    console.log(pairs[pair]['adxValue']['adx']);
```

The following line should "assign" the value to `adxValue` in pairs[pair] object:

```
pairs[pair]['adxValue'] = pairs[pair]['adx'].nextValue({period: adxPeriods, close: price[2], high: price[3], low: price[4]});
```

Instead I get an object with 3 values inside `adxValue - {adx: "", pdi: "", mdi: ""}`
The problem is that I can't access the first line.
When I try to print `adxValue` with the following code:

```
console.log(pairs[pair]['adxValue']['adx']);
```

I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'adx' of undefined

Does anybody know what the issue is?

Comment: It would help to know what `SMA` and `ADX` look like. Specifically, what do their `nextValue` methods return? Basically what's happening is that `nextValue` is, for whatever, reason returning `undefined`.

Comment: thanks for quick response!  SMA nextvalue method return single value, so there is no problem - I can access this value from pairs[pair]['smaValue']. But in case of adx - nextvalue returns object with 3 properties. I can see it if I print console.log(pairs[pair]['adxValue']).   My problem is i can't separate one of these values inside adxValue and get only first one.  When I try to do so I receive stated above error...

Comment: This is the output I get from console.log(pairs[pair]['adxValue']):  { adx: 18.713471063563393,
  pdi: 32.57746878379387,
  mdi: 23.66443474340118 }

Comment: I need to extract 'adx' from the output above... to use it in code later...

Comment: nextValue(price) {
        let result = this.generator.next(price).value;
        if (result != undefined && result.adx != undefined) {
            return { adx: this.format(result.adx), pdi: this.format(result.pdi), mdi: this.format(result.mdi) };
        }